# SharePoint Framework Extension 'Invalid Package' error

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am currently working on a SPFx extension to add JavaScript on all modern pages. I am following [Chris O'Brien's blog](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html) to create this. I was able to create and debug it but when I package it up and upload to app catalog, It shows Valid App Package = NO. See image below.

[image]

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you trying to install the extension? In SharePoint Online or onprem?

Comment: I am developing for SharePoint Online only. I tried three different tenant including O365 early access and developer tenants.

Comment: If you go to the app catalog list view settings, there is a field that is the reason it isn't valid.  Can you add that field to the view and see what it says?   (We're making that field show by default in an upcoming patch)

Comment: The field name that @PatMill_MSFT was talking about is "App Package Error Message".

Answer (score -2):

Currently `.sppkg` can be deployed to SharePoint Online tenants only. You have to wait for on-pren support.